# MS Excel, how to update the choice list of a group of comboboxes

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've created a MS Excel workbook, which consists of two worksheets.
The second worksheet contains a list of items, the first contains a table, and one of the columns of the table is a bunch of comboboxes, referring to the list in the second worksheet.

Now I've realised that the list in the second worksheet is not complete, I have added some items. In order for those new items to be taken into account by the comboboxes in the first worksheet, I need to redefine all of them.

I'm wondering if there is no easier way to do this: I would like to create one combobox, based on a list of entries, and a list of comboboxes, based on that first one. If I decide to add something to the list of entries, I'd just redefine the first combobox and all others get updated automatically.

Is there any way to get this done?
Thanks
Dominique

Comment: Some examples (screenshots, etc) would help someone better understand what you're working with. What have you tried already? Off the top of my head, it would be better to define your comboboxes with a named range. That way, if you add criteria to the range, you just updated the cells in the named range, and any combobox that refers to that range would be updated.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, JRichall, but you might put this as a real answer, because indeed working with names indeed solves my issue.
I admit, once I have given a name to my list of entries, I needed to use the "Name manager" in the "Formulas" tab in order to modify it (which is not very straightforward), but once I get the hang of it, it's working great!

Comment: Thanks @Dominique. I just added it as an answer. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By setting the values for your comboboxes as a named range, you can easily change their contents by editing the range you use. 
- Select the cells that contain you list of combobox entries
- On the top left, where the cell selection is displayed, click and name the range.
- Then, if you ever need to add more or change it, utilize the Name Manager under the formulas tab.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]